# Is Heath Ledger seen in the restaurant scene in The Dark Knight?

Tags: the-dark-knight, identify-this-actor

Any one observe this? It's interesting to see Heath Ledger in the restaurant ..

[image: batman]

Is that really Heath Ledger in the restaurant scene in *The Dark Knight*?

Comment: This is from The Dark Knight (2008). Harvey Dent was not in Batman Begins.

Comment: Nice observation, however there is no reference on internet. So he is not heath ledger

Comment: Uh, could it be we already had that question here once?

Comment: We had a very similar question which asked about a bigger crowd scene. I suspect it was deleted.

Comment: Uh, Heath Ledger because of ...what? The friggin' hair cut?

Comment: Highly doubt that it's Heath Ledger, it doesn't really look like him from the first screen shot.

Answer (score 5):

With about 99% certainty, I can tell you its not Heath Ledger, but a guy with similar hair.  If you blow up the photo, the differences between Heath and that extra become more pronounced.  You can see better photos [here](http://www.chud.com/140742/does-the-joker-have-an-extra-hidden-appearance-in-the-dark-knight/).  If it was meant for the joker to be at the restaurant, the scars would be evident, as in [this photo](http://images-cdn.moviepilot.com/image/upload/c_fill,h_800,w_1200/t_mp_quality/joker-cop-there-s-a-secret-hidden-behind-heath-ledger-s-joker-jpeg-194338.jpg) when he is seen dressed as a cop.